# How can we call the Vue methods in Kendo Grid Detailtable Datasource change event

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

How can we call the Vue methods in Kendo Grid **Detailtable** Datasource change event?

I am able to call the native kendo grid change event like below,

```
dataSource: {
      data: data,
      change: function () {

      },
```

I tried to call vue method in datasource change event like below, but it is not calling the method and not even throwing any error.

```
dataSource: {
      data: data,
      'v-on:change': function () {

      },
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Show us more code. Where are you invoking this? It should be within the `created()` function of your component, and using `fat arrow syntax () => {}` should give you `this` which would let you call a function defined in your `methods` object.

Comment: I am invoking this inside vue methods (detailInit) as this is detailTable of my main grid .
Below is my code.

methods: {
    detailInit: function (e) {
      $('<div/>').appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          data: data,
          filter: {
            field: 'CustomerSiteID',
            operator: 'eq',
            value: e.data.CustomerSiteID
          },
          change: function () {
    
    }
  }
   })
 }